# Can we use both MUI makeStyles and Theming in _app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, theming

I'm making a tricky nav component using [MUI Persistent Drawers](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/) with a React + Next structure. In order to get the content shrinking thanks to the state change, I had to put the whole navigation system **inside of the _app.js file** instead of having it in a distinct component.

Even though it clearly works, I wonder if it'll not impact rendering and performance once built. The `makeStyles((theme)` seems to work just fine but is not highlighted in VScode, probably because I used both of **makeStyles**, **useTheme** and **ThemeProvider** in the same file, as below :

```
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({ ...
    (className example:) appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
}, ... etc
```

Was it a good idea to put it all together in _app.js, or do I need to refactor everything into a new component passing props to parent somehow ?

Thanks for considering, best regards to all of you

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to put your theme inside a folder theme/theme.js and use createMuiTheme then in your app.js wrap your whole component with the theme provider ! That would spread your theme across the app and let you use it where you want ! Is the convention we got with material-ui.

theme/theme.js:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

export const themeObject = {
  palette: {
    primary: { main: "#333333" },
    secondary: { main: "#FD8C7C" },
  },
  backgroundColor: {
    primary: { main: "#FEF8F8" },
    secondary: { main: "#FFFFFF" },
  },
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 960,
      lg: 1280,
      xl: 1920,
    },
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiDivider: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      },
    },
  },
}

export default createMuiTheme(themeObject)
```

pages/app,js:

```
import React from "react"
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles"
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box"
import defaultTheme from "../theme/theme"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
       ...
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default App
```

component/SideBar.js:

```
import React from "react"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  drawer: {
    width: theme.sidebar.width,
    color: theme.palette.primary
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
      top: "unset",
    },
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: "hidden",
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    },
  },
  expandButton: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(-2.5),
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2.5),
    },
  },
}))

export default function Sidebar(props) {
const classes = UseStyles()
  return (...)
}
```

In the SideBar you can see that i have use the theme.zindex.drawer who come from directly theme.js.
I also recommend you to go check this [MUI THEMING](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/) that would let you dive into the theming more deeply !

Comment: Hello and thank you for responding ! 
I'm already doing this, in fact - problem is I can't use the persistent version of the drawer properly if it's not directly placed into _app.js (otherwise, it can't right shift the rest of the app when opening).
My whole problem is that I must have classNames propreties in the same file than the ThemeProvider...

Comment: that because you have probably miss something with your setup of the theming its not normal at all the themeProvider is here for spread the theming across your app.
Give me a link to a github repository i gonna check after my workday and create a pull request with the modification ! If this is ok for you accept my answer on stackoverflow 

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a shareable code, but I'll look for a way to debug ThemeProvider or simply pass on some props in order to have a cleaner app.js. Thank you for your concern